# Is is possible to update ruby to version ruby 1.9.3 with rails 2.3 project (existing code)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-1.9.3

Is it possible to update ruby to version ruby 1.9.2 with rails 2.3.11 project (existing code).

Comment: My advice: Its very hard to upgrade rails 2.x site to ruby 1.9.x First upgrade it to rails 3.x and then try to upgrade to ruby 1.9.x

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that because Rails 2.3.11 can support ruby 1.9.2. But can be hard to do. Rails 3.x is more focus on ruby 1.9.x. The Rails 4.x can only support ruby >= 1.9.2

Comment: actually, rails 4 will support only >= 1.9.3